# React.js how can i get subcollecion datas in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It's a basic question. I can add data for each user in on users own collection. (users/user-id/notes). How can i get datas from this subcollection? I read some informations about ref.parent.parent.id, but i can't get it. Can you help me ?

my addNewNote function codes:

```
const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
const notesRef = database.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("notes");


 const addNewNote = async (newNote) => {
    await notesRef.add({
      note: {
        title: newNote.title,
        content: newNote.content,
      },
    });
  };
```

my homepage (also notes should seems here):
Here, I know   ->>>   "database
.collection("users")
.doc(uid)
.collection("notes")
.onSnapshot((querySnapshot)" --->   this is wrong, i need to do like parent.parent.id or something like that, but i can't get it.

```
<div className="home">
        {database
          .collection("users")
          .doc(uid)
          .collection("notes")
          .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc, index) => {
              <Note
              key={index}
              id={index}
              title={doc.data().title}
              content={doc.data().content}
              onDelete={deleteNote}
            />
            });
          })}
      </div>
```

Also here i have uploaded an image in firestore.
[image]

Here my app screenshot (without firebase, with just an array), and i read them with map function.

without firebase, here codes for array:
Adding note:

```
setNotes((prevNotes) => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
  };
```

Reading note with <Note/ >:

```
{notes.map((noteItem, index) => {
              return (
                <Note
                  key={index}
                  id={index}
                  title={noteItem.title}
                  content={noteItem.content}
                  onDelete={deleteNote}
                />
              );
            })}
```

[image]

Comment: Why isn't the `database .collection("users") .doc(uid) .collection("notes")` ideal?

Comment: @Dharmaraj because there are lots of users in database, and if they have on they own notes collection, i think reading data will be easy. Apart from that, user just can see own notes, not the other user's notes

Comment: Using that is completely fine. You can specify security rules so that users can read/write their own notes only. I can help with security rules if you are interested. I think that'll be ideal solution

Comment: @Dharmaraj of course you can write, i want to learn all of the solutions :-)

Comment: I've posted an answer. You can accept/upvote if that was helpful else feel free to ask further questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with using reactfire. It helps a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use security rules to make sure user can read/write their own notes only.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userID}/notes/{noteID} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
    }
  }
}
```

The variables userID and noteID are wildcards that means they'll take up value of resource path being accessed.

To query the notes of current user, you can use the same query.

```
const notesRef = database.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("notes") 
notesRef.get().then(notesSnapshot => {
  console.log(`${notesSnapshot.size} notes fetched!`)
})
```

Comment: I tried this, but i need to for loop for reading all document. Like: database
          .collection("users")
          .doc(uid)
          .collection("notes")
          .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc, index) => {
              <Note
              key={index}
              id={index}
              title={doc.data().title}
              content={doc.data().content}
              onDelete={deleteNote}
            />
            });
          })

because here i have index number

Comment: @coldasspirit do you need realtime listener there or do you need to fetch data once only ?

Comment: I need realtime listener, becaues my app is note app, if you add note, you want see the note at the same time

Comment: @coldasspirit your code seems right to me. Just update the security rules as mentioned. Is there anything specific as not intended?

Comment: I add screenshot from my app, and also i add codes without firebase. I mean codes in below for array. I want to like this, but using firebase. It has to be permanent...